# passing variable with an custom action WIX installer

Tags: vb.net, wix

I have a problem with passing the required variable. the problem is this:

I am creating and installer that needs to work on both x86 and x64. changing the installation destination I manage with the following code:

```
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH)=x64?>        
    <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesX86"?>
    <?define FOLDER_NAME = Program Files (x86) ?>

    <?else?>
    <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder"?>
    <?define FOLDER_NAME = Program Files ?>   

    <?endif?>

    <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)" Name="$(var.FOLDER_NAME)">
```

this works fine, however I also have an CA.dll that needs to get the variable FOLDER_NAME since the script makes some changes in files and the path to those files need to be changed as well in order to point towards the right location.

I do have a custom action that transfers propertys to the same script

```
    <Property Id ="MACHINE_ID_NUMBER" Secure ="yes">
  <![CDATA[]]>
</Property>

<Property Id ="MACHINE_TYPE" Secure ="yes">
  <![CDATA[]]>
</Property>

<CustomAction
  Id="SetProperties"
  Property="ValueAdaptionScript"
  HideTarget="no"
  Value="MachineID=[MACHINE_ID_NUMBER];MachineType=[MACHINE_TYPE]"
  />

<CustomAction
  Id="ValueAdaptionScript"
  BinaryKey="StringTransfer"
  DllEntry="CustomAction1"
  Execute="deferred"
  Impersonate="no"
  Return="check"
  />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetProperties" Before="ValueAdaptionScript" />
  <Custom Action="ValueAdaptionScript" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem is that I am not able to get those two pieces of code combined and working. the problem is that I can't get the value of the variable in an property as is recuired to use it in the custom action.

what am I missing to get it working or am I doing it completely the wrong way?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, it turned out to be pretty easy I was just looking in the wrong direction.

this is what I did:

```
    <Property Id ="PLATFORM_PROGRAM_FILES" Secure ="yes">
  <![CDATA[$(var.FOLDER_NAME)]]>
</Property>
```

all I had to do was to give the property the variable.